# Como alterar o valor do coringa do Prepared Statement?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Suponha que eu tenha uma consulta com `prepare` que está desta forma:

```
select senha from usuarios where id=? //or id2=?, array($id,$id2); (é só um exemplo).
```

A minha intenção é trocar o `?` por qualquer outro valor que eu escolher dentro do array e não que ele pegue na ordem que se encontra dentro do mesmo.

Por exemplo o primeiro `id=?` pegar o valor da posição 2 do array.
Estou usando banco de dados postgresql e linguagem de programação PHP

Answer (score 2):

Use as funções `bindParam` e `bindValue`. Por exemplo:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
```

Ou:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $name);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $value);
```

Comment: Estou usando a biblioteca AdoDB.
Tentei desta forma mas não consegui, alguma sugestão?


$rs = $db->Execute('select name from table where val=:key', array('key' => 10));

Comment: Pela documentação do ADODB (http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm), me parece ser isso mesmo. Rodando a query diretamente no banco de dados, você obtém algum resultado?

Comment: Esta reposta pressupõe o uso do PDO, não? Acho que o ADO não tem `bindParam`.

Comment: Na verdade os parâmetros vêm no `array` que é o segundo parãmetro do método `Execute`.

Comment: a ADO possuí bind. No banco de dados não cheguei a testar ainda mas no debug do php ele acusa erro próximo aos ":" após o sinal de "=".

Comment: Tente separá-los por espaço ou usar `?` ao invés de parâmetros nomeados.